# Why are quotes invisible in this SE site?

Tags: support, spoilers

I was exploring the site and saw this. I haven't met the same thing on other SE sites:

[image]

Maybe it's my Windows fault that I can't see it properly? Or perhaps that's a feature for *puzzling* the look of the site?

I can see the texts in them just if I put my mouse cursor on them.

Comment: *the sight of so many sites hurts...*

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Those aren't quotes; they're [*spoilers*](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/editing-help#spoilers), intended to not accidentally spoil the solution to a puzzle in case you want to figure it out yourself. They're frequently used on Puzzling, and see moderate use on sites like Movies & TV, Science Fantasy & Fiction, and Gaming. On most Stack Exchange sites there's simply no use case for them.

You can either hover over them to show them temporarily (until you move out of them) or click on them to show them permanently (that is, as long as you stay on the page).

Comment: Is this a new feature? I have seen these spoilers in other SE sites like movies site too. But they were permanently viewable there. In movies, it is also important not to show spoilers

Comment: Then they weren't properly formatted as spoilers. They've been around since December 2010: [Add markdown support for hidden-until-you-click text (aka spoilers)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/1191/295232)

Comment: @aminabzz Quotes look like spoilers but without the hidden text. You can click on spoilers to see them without having to hover over them with your mouse. Quotes in Markdown are denoted by `>` whereas spoilers (SE-specific extension) are denoted by `>!`